# Why does gelling sugar lose its gelling property after some time?

Tags: storage-lifetime, jam, gelling-agents

[Gelling sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelling_sugar) (also called jam sugar or jelly sugar) is used for making fruit jams. It is a mixture of sugar and pectin. Properly stored sugar has a near infinite shelf life but gelling sugar only has a shelf life of a few month. Aferwards it still works like usual sugar but does not work as a gelling agent anymore.

Why does that happen?

Comment: Depending on the answer, this might be more suitable for chemistry SE. Please migrate if appropriate.